# Erro xml eSocial: Assinatura do evento inválida. Apenas um Elemento 'KeyInfo/X509Data' é requerido/permitido

Tags: xml, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital, api

Estou com o erro: Assinatura do evento inválida. Apenas um Elemento 'KeyInfo/X509Data' é requerido/permitido

Antes disso recebi o erro que deveria alterar o transform method da assinatura para:

```xml
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315">
```

Antes estava:

```xml
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
```

link utilizado como base para assinar o xml: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/11/14/using-sha256-with-the-signedxml-class/

Observação: após utilizar o método pra assinar, reparei que não cria essa parte:

```xml
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data> 
    <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>         
  </X509Data> 
</KeyInfo>
```

Pode ser isso? Se sim o que pode estar faltando para criar essa parte no XML?

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema, porém em PHP, vou deixar registrado minha solução caso alguém tenha a mesma dificuldade. O erro estava na conversão do certificado pfx. A conversão do certificado pfx para pem deve ser através do seguinte comando openssl: `openssl pkcs12 -in /var/cert.pfx -out var/cert.pem -nodes`

Answer (score 0):

Consegui identificar o problema. Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema segue a solução

Faltava incluir o código:

```
Dim KeyInfo As KeyInfo = New KeyInfo()
Dim keyInfoData As KeyInfoX509Data = New KeyInfoX509Data(cert)
KeyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData)
SignedXml.KeyInfo = KeyInfo
```

Para adicionar as informações sobre o certificado abaixo da assinatura